# Raspberry pi connection to remote web server and database connections

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi

So I'm currently working on a personal project to automate some processes around the house using a raspberry pi. But i would like to do something more than what i've seen around the web.
My idea is to connect to a webserver to login and i'll have a database on the webserver where i store a unique identifier associated to the user and the device, so i can have multiple people accessing their unique device from the same webserver. After the access part there should be a web interface (javascript probably, unless someone has a better suggestion...) to run some premade scripts on the pi and show the results via and apache/nginx (not decided yet...) server...

I'm having some problems though, because i have no ssh access to the webserver (and the hosting company wont give it to me because it poses security issues), i'm seeing no way to connect to the raspberry pi from the outer web (what i intended was a [reverse ssh tunnel](https://drjohnstechtalk.com/blog/2013/02/ssh-access-to-your-raspberry-pi-from-anywhere/))

Also, i'm not being able to install web2py on the pi, and i was trying because it seems like such an amazing framework, but i wonder if i should install it on the webserver instead and then just serve the python to the pi or only the command to run the python on the pi itself (the scripts hosted in the pi or the web server?)

I have found some amazing tutorials on how to do amazing stuff and somewhat like what i need, the thing is i want to host the web interface in a remote webserver, rather than in the pi, like some good tutorials i found do, the best i've found: [Closest to my project i can find](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-home-automation/#step2)

I'm sorry if this is a clumsy post, but i can't seem to explain better than this, if you need any help, just comment and i'll try to answer by editing the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider Amazon Web Services hosting.
They offer a free-tier Virtual Private Server level which you have full control over (including ssh).

I would recommend running a single instance of the website (web2py) on your amazon server and have that co-ordinate your army of pi's.

Comment: i had thought of the VPS, and i'm actually willing to ask a friend that runs a hosting company for some time on a vps server to test it, but if that amazon thing works, i dont need to bother him :D
Also, this is my first time working with web2py, do you have any idea of how i could run the python scripts on the pi?

Comment: You can make it as complicated as you want. You could be using reverse ssh-methods OR just have the pi's open a socket to the VPS and listen for any requests/commands. (beware you will want to encrypt traffic)

Comment: wouldnt that cause problems with firewalls? im only wanting to use the reverse tunneling because it will be seen as an outbound connection, not an inbound connection...

Comment: Having the pi connect to the server through a raw socket should be seen as an outbound connection.